# How did Romilly's food supplies last 23 years?

Tags: interstellar, food

The spaceship, *Endurance*, was small, barely having enough space for 4 astronauts. One astronaut, Romilly, was left behind on the *Endurance* for 23 years. He hibernated for much of that time, but he still visibly aged so he must have spent much time awake.

**How did he get food?**

We don't see hydroponic gardens on the *Endurance*. The spaceship is too small for a huge storage cabinet full of food.

**Is there anything in the movie, [Interstellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)), or the novelization that mentions food supply?**

Comment: Dupe? https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35403/how-did-romilly-survive-23-years-on-the-endurance

Comment: @Gallifreyan How could it? Those are two different sites.

Comment: @Cahir you don't say? :D I simply meant that the answer over there may also be the answer here.

Answer (score 16):

No specifics are given in the film or the film's novelisation regarding the food situation. We know from the dialogue that he used the cryo-sleep pods to hibernate for a couple of long periods (10+ years apiece?) in addition to spending several years on his own.

> **BRAND:** *Why didn’t you sleep?*
>
> **ROMILLY:** *I did a couple of stretches. But I stopped believing you were coming back, and something seems wrong about dreaming your life
>   away. I learned what I could from studying the black hole, but I
>   couldn’t send anything to your father. We’ve been receiving, but
>   nothing gets out.*
>
> <sub><sup>*Interstellar: Original Script*</sup></sub>

Assuming he was fully awake for three entire years, he'd have needed at around 1500 calories a day which equates to around 700g per day of [astronaut food](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/living/spacefood/). This figure might be even even less given that food-science has evidently improved in the future. Romilly would have needed a grand total of 700(ish) kilos of food, an amount that could *easily* have been stored in one of the [two large habitat modules](http://endurance.interstellarmovie.net/).

> ***The Habitat Modules also contain the stores of consumables required
>   for the mission.*** Water and air recycling units as well as primary life
>   support are housed in the Habitat Modules below the floor of the crew
>   cabins,
>
> <sub><sup>http://endurance.interstellarmovie.net/ [link obsolete]</sup></sub>

He might also have been cutting into the "***surface mission stores"***, which presumably also contain some food.

> ***The lower sections of these pods contain surface mission stores*** and
>   can be detached and ferried down to a planet’s surface using the
>   Lander craft.
>
> <sub><sup>http://endurance.interstellarmovie.net/</sup></sub>

---

For the record, 700 kilogrammes of Skittles looks like this. If the food of the future was in pill form, there would have been enough space in the hab module for approximately 100-150 times as much as the amount below.

[image: a big crate of colorfulr Skittles]

Comment: @Lordofdark - I assume that in the future, all food will come in Skittle form.

Comment: “700 kilogrammes of Skittles looks like this” — _WANT_

Comment: Apparently so will [gym equipment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhQ0Hm.jpg)

Comment: @Edlothiad - Is there [anything they can't do](https://media.photoblog.com/photos/168257-1449491591-0.jpg)?

Comment: @Valorum, they don't help when on the toilet... *Insert mental image here*

Comment: I don't believe a major problem with the food would be the size, it would be weight. Unless they somehow manufactured food out of materials already outside of earth's gravity they would have had to ship up 70Kg of food from earth, which is a lot. Though I suppose that mass pales in comparison to the mass of all the humans and the ship itself.

Comment: @Gandalf'sFISTS - The blurb on the website indicates that the ship was built in orbit by robots, with parts that were slung into orbit by Saturn boosters. The food would be a negligible amount (*1/70th*) of the max payload of a single rocket.

Comment: @Valorum I'm going to ask the obvious question. How does there JUST HAPPEN to be a picture of exactly the amount of skittles you want to depict?

Comment: @Broklynite - The Internet is like the bountiful ocean. It provides.

Comment: Second link now redirects to Warner Bros' website and [its Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404180315/http://endurance.interstellarmovie.net/) seems to load forever. If you've got a replacement...

Comment: @Jenayah - That's really annoying. Their old website had some really nice interactive features. WB keeps doing this!

Comment: @Valorum yeah, you'd think Warner Bros could afford to keep these promotional websites up. I mean, if it's not a money thing, what is it? Loss of interest in the movie over time? Sheesh

Comment: @Jenayah - Unless someone grabbed and is willing to host the code, it's lost forever.